# RecyclerView does not update ROOM Database although data exists

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

My `Entity` class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @NonNull
    public ArrayList<String> getValues(){
        return values;
    }

    @NonNull
    public ArrayList<String> getDates(){
        return dates;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getType_counter() {
        return type_counter;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getWhere_counter() {
        return where_counter;
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "d")
    @TypeConverters({Converters.class})
    public ArrayList<String> dates;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    @TypeConverters({Converters.class})
    public ArrayList<String> values;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    public String type_counter;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "location")
    public String where_counter;
}
```

I have one RecyclerView which shows only type and location and when you click on any item it goes to another activity where another RecyclerView shows values and dates of this particular User (by Id) as arrays.

My problem is this: user of my app can either create new `User` object or `update` it (add value and date to ArrayLists) and when updating RecyclerView is not working properly.

Suppose I have two `User` objects and my database looks like this:

[image]

My fist object has two values and dates but RecyclerView shows only one.

[image]

When I add another value and date to the second `User` object, RecyclerView shows two elements in both objects.

This is how I update values:

```
private void saveNewValue(String value, String type, String location){

        // Getting current date
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String formattedDate = df.format(c);

        userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

        // checking if the counter exists
        int mList = userViewModel.setTypeLocation(type, location);

        if (mList == 0){
            //Saving new User
            User user = new User();

            if (user.values == null){
                user.values = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            if (user.dates == null){
                user.dates = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            user.values.add(value);
            user.dates.add(formattedDate);
            user.type_counter = type;
            user.where_counter = location;

            userViewModel.insert(user);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            //Getting current data
            User mUser = userViewModel.getUserWithLocationType(type, location);
            ArrayList<String> values_user = mUser.getValues();
            ArrayList<String> dates_user = mUser.getDates();

            // Updating arrays
            values_user.add(value);
            dates_user.add(formattedDate);

            // Creating new User object with updated values
            User updatedUser = new User();
            updatedUser.id = mUser.getId();
            updatedUser.type_counter = type;
            updatedUser.where_counter = location;
            updatedUser.values = values_user;
            updatedUser.dates = dates_user;

            userViewModel.update(updatedUser);
            //userAdapter.notifyItemChanged();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

This is `Adapter` class for an already described `RecyclerView`:

```
public class CalculationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CalculationAdapter.CalcViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mValues;
    private ArrayList<String> mDates;
    private User mUser;

    public CalculationAdapter(Context ctx){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        mContext = ctx;
    }

    public void setUser(User user){
        mUser = user;
        mValues = user.getValues();
        mDates = user.getDates();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("values", String.valueOf(mValues));
        Log.i("dates", String.valueOf(mDates));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CalculationAdapter.CalcViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculations_item, parent, false);
        CalculationAdapter.CalcViewHolder holder = new CalculationAdapter.CalcViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CalculationAdapter.CalcViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (mValues != null & mDates != null){
            String value = mValues.get(position);
            String date = mDates.get(position);
            holder.setValuesDates(value, date, position);
        }
        else{
            holder.mValue.setText("No value");
            holder.mDate.setText("No date");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mValues != null){
            return mValues.size();
        } else return 0;
    }

    class CalcViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mValue;
        private TextView mDate;
        private int mPosition;

        public CalcViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_value);
            mDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_date);

        }

        public void setValuesDates(String value, String date, int position){
            mValue.setText(value);
            mDate.setText(date);
            mPosition = position;
        }
    }

}
```

This is ViewModel class:

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private UserDao userDao;
    private AppDatabase appDatabase;
    private LiveData<List<User>> mAllUsers;
    private LiveData<String[]> mAllLocations;
    private LiveData<User> mUser;
    private int UserLocationTypeExists;

    public UserViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        userDao = appDatabase.userDao();
        mAllUsers = userDao.getAllValues();
        mAllLocations = userDao.getAllLocations();
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        mUser = userDao.getUserWithId(id);
    }

    public User getUserWithLocationType(String type, String location){
        return userDao.getUserwithLocationType(type, location);
    }

    public int setTypeLocation(String type, String location){
        UserLocationTypeExists = userDao.UserWithTypeLocationExists(type, location);
        return UserLocationTypeExists;
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        new UpdateAsyncTask(userDao).execute(user);
    }

    public void insert(User user){
        new InsertAsyncTask(userDao).execute(user);
    }

    public void delete(User user){
        new DeleteAsyncTask(userDao).execute(user);
    }

    public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers(){
        return mAllUsers;
    }

    public LiveData<String[]> getAllLocations() {
        return mAllLocations;
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUserAtId(){
        return mUser;
    }

    private class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {

        UserDao userDao;

        public InsertAsyncTask(UserDao userDao) {
            this.userDao = userDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
            userDao.insertValue(users[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class DeleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {

        UserDao userDao;

        public DeleteAsyncTask(UserDao userDao) {
            this.userDao = userDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
            userDao.deleteValue(users[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class UpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {

        UserDao userDao;

        public UpdateAsyncTask(UserDao userDao) {
            this.userDao = userDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
            userDao.update(users[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Activity` where I have `RecyclerView`:

```
public class CalculationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private int id_counter;
    private UserViewModel userViewModel;
    private CalculationAdapter calcAdapter;
    private int rate;
    private String value1, date1, value2, date2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculation);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            id_counter = extras.getInt("id");
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_calc);
        calcAdapter = new CalculationAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(calcAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
        userViewModel.setId(id_counter);
        userViewModel.getUserAtId().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(User user) {
                calcAdapter.setUser(user);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Could somebody please help me figure out why doesn't my RecyclerView update data correctly? Thanks in advance.

I can add more info if necessary.

This is `TypeConverters.class`:

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static ArrayList<String> fromString(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(list);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I saved different values in the database. Here is how the database looking:

[image]

This is `Activity1`:

[image]

When I click on both items they both show value `2222`:

[image]

Output of `SetUser` method (when I click on each of the items):

```
I/values: [2222]
I/dates: [27-Juli-2022]

I/values: [2222]
I/dates: [27-Juli-2022]
```

Comment: Where the `saveNewValue` method resides?

Comment: In the MainActivity, where user adds new values. From MainActivity you go to Activity1 where the first RecyclerView is (with types and locations) and from there you go to Activity2 where is the RecyclerView that does not update properly.

Comment: Activity2 is the `CalculationActivity` whose recyclerview does not update correctly, and the `CalculationAdapter` is its adapter, is that right? Can you describe more how is that recyclerview supposed to update properly to help me to figure out the exact functionality?

Comment: As far as I see you're using *TypeConverter*s for storing the value list, can you show us its implementation as well?

Comment: In your `CalculationAdapter`, `setUser` method you log the values. Are the values printed to the log correct?

Comment: Activity2 is CalculationActivity, that is right, I made some edits. I want my RecyclerView to display as many items as I have in my ArrayLists in the database. So if I have two values in my first object and one value in second object I want it to display two and one accordingly.

Comment: As far as I understand; in the first screenshot when you clicked to **Gas - Bathroom** item in the list then you will list its dates and values if any, using the item's ID which is 12 in this example. But the problem is, in the value listing screen, not all the values of ID 12 are listed. Do I get it right?

Comment: Yes, they are only shown if the other user object has two values as well. If Id 12 has 2 values, but id 13 has one value then when I click on id12 only one value is shown although there're 2 in the database.

Comment: Since you use the same values for all records, makes it difficult to detect where the values come from. You'd better make an example with different value and date records for each location and user. Do you mind making it and updating the database pictures accordingly?

Comment: And share the log outputs in the `setUser` method please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246817/discussion-between-alice-p-and-kozmotronik).

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake... I've been sending ID to Activity2 the wrong way. I've been getting it in the `onBindViewHolder` method which goes over all the elements and which is why I got only values from the last saved element. I needed to get ID in the `Holder` class in `OnClick` method. Thanks for all the help anyway.